# Simple JQuery .fadeIn event not working correctly on my browser

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm new to JQuery and trying out some basic events.

I used the fadeIn event on my website under construction page ([my website](http://www.julianamlinder.com)

The code I'm using is as follows, applying only to the three present selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#logo').fadeIn(3000);
$('#heading').delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
$('#tagline').delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

});
```

While my boyfriend says it works in his Chrome browser every single time he refreshes, it doesn't always work in mine. Sometimes the image appears, sometimes it doesnt. Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it doesn't.

Could this be my internet connection? Or is it my code?

I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Juliana

Comment: _it works in his Chrome browser every single time he refreshes, it doesn't always work in mine_... what is yours? IE, Firefox etc?

Comment: I have the same exact version of Chrome that he does and sometimes it will load out of order, sometimes the image won't load, sometimes it will all work...it happens randomly which is what confuses me...

Comment: @juliana It's also happening randomly for me.. some reason it seems like the logo div isn't fading in

Comment: I am in Chrome 23 on OSX and I haven't seen any issues. The large image shows and then the other text below it loads after. It's possible that the logo isn't downloaded until after the page html has loaded and rendered and the animation has started, which would cause it to not show until the page was refreshed.

Comment: Does it work consistently if you refresh with ctrl+F5 vs just F5? I'm thinking the image isn't loading fast enough or at all randomly. I would expect jsut refreshing with F5 to work fine after the first load. If this is the case, use `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: side note: You are loading a ton of fonts that you aren't using.
`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Arvo|PT+Sans|Quicksand|PT+Serif+Caption|Josefin+Sans|Kameron|Muli|Raleway|Hammersmith+One|Merriweather|Vollkorn|Card o|Quattrocento' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial|Great+Vibes|Cedarville+Cursive|Raleway|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: @Kevin B it looks like the $(window).load() has fixed the problem but I'm not sure it's so in other browsers, I'll have to check it out but thanks! As for the refresh with ctrl F5, my mac doesn't seem to do anything when I try it. Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: @pferdefleisch true...noted ;) guess I'm a font hoarder oops!

Answer (score 2):

I'll keep this answer here, but the more obvious and *much* easier non-overkill method would likely be what **@[Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869117/simple-jquery-fadein-event-not-working-correctly-on-my-browser#comment19099592_13869117)** suggested in the comments above and using `$(window).load()` which waits for all page content to be loaded as well instead of `$(document).ready()` which waits only for the HTML DOM to be loaded.

---

What you probably want to do is ensure that the image has been loaded before you try and fade it in. If it's not loaded when the page is finished being rendered and your JS runs, it will not show up. Then you will refresh the browser and it will work that time.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#logo img").bind("load", function () { 
        if(!$("#logo").is(":visible")) {
             $('#logo').fadeIn(3000);
        }
    });

    $('#logo').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#heading').delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $('#tagline').delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

​});
```

What you're doing is first saying that as soon as the image has finished loading, and if it hasn't already been made visible, fade it in. But the problem with that is if the image has already been downloaded before, this won't ever actually fire. So you need to have the normal fadein() below it that always runs as well.

The main problem with this is your timing will be off unless (possibly only by < 1 second) unless you want to halt all animations until the image has been loaded for sure.

[Here's a fiddle to play around with](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/7BJMc/)

Comment: Thanks, that's a really helpful tip. But it looks like just switching my call from $(document).ready() to $(window).load() made all the difference. Would this be more of a safety net though? Just in case that doesn't hold up in other browsers?

Comment: I updated my answer, I think Kevin's answer about using .load() is the better solution and my answer is a bit overkill. I'd stick with using that. But it never hurts to learn more stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time anyway! Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the images aren't done loading or simply don't load in some cases, which causes them to just appear rather than fading in because they were not visible when the fadeIn occurred. To avoid this, make sure they are first loaded by using the window load event.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // do stuff
});
```